# What sources of vision/information can a player character utilize while burrowing without taking an action to do so?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, magic, vision-and-light

Mole-man is a player character with a burrowing speed from [Claws of the Umber Hulk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/claws-of-the-umber-hulk) and is under the ground. That character is effectively in full cover, blinded and holding their breath. What character class, subclass, subclass options, spells, and/or magic item combinations would provide mole-man sufficient information of the surface to poke its head up each turn in a combat scenario without being within mêlée reach of enemies?

Most of all UA content is on the table. No classes have been determined. My personal preference is towards Artificer Armourer allowing a more martial play style using the lightning launcher while the hands are occupied by Claws of the Umber Hulk. Ideally the build should be fully functional by levels 9-10.

In summary the objectives is:
Player Character can determine with some accuracy the location of enemies on/above the surface while burrowed without using an action each turn.

Currently known options are:

1. [Arcane Eye](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-eye) - 4th level slot, concentration and only 30ft vision radius
2. ⭐ [Order of Scribes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#OrderofScribes) wizard's *Manifest Mind* - Best option thus far, 6 lvls wizard
3. [Wand of Enemy Detection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-enemy-detection) - Direction but not distance within 60ft
4. [Ring of X-ray Vision](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-x-ray-vision) - Only works within 3ft of the surface, less if not soil

Comment: The usual solution is blindsight or tremorsense, not remote viewing. Have you looked into those abilities?

Comment: Blindsense doesn't work to see through full cover that the dirt creates between you and the surface. And I am unaware of any ways of gaining tremor sense

Comment: Scribes wizard gets this feature with Manifest Mind - are you asking how to get this with an existing character, or only if it’s possible to create a character that can do it?

Comment: Oh the scribes wizard might be the best way. Not an existing character. I was just playing with the idea of a burrowing player character based around Claws of the Umber Hulk. The main challenge being that your hands are permanently occupied by the claws. My initial plan was Artificer armourer using the lightning launcher and maybe a splash of arcane trickster to use the mage hand. The new Thri-kreen solves the hand occupancy problem but not the vision.

Comment: the primary goal is to know where to surface to avoid walking into enemies. Bonus point if the condition of the surface can be determined (such as an active aoe effect) or can determine if one is about to burrow through the ceiling of a cavern.

Comment: Do you have a DM who enjoys flavour, or sticks with RAW?

Comment: Flavour is pretty open but the mechanics are RAW

Comment: What's the purpose of the star emoji (⭐) in the post? Is it just to indicate your own preferred option from the list of known options?

Answer (score 3):

Additional options open to level 10 characters to determine creatures on the surface, both from Core Rules, without using an action each turn

- **Clairvoyance** (level 3 Bard, Wizard, Sorcerer, Cleric)

> You create an invisible sensor within range in a location familiar to you (a place you have visited or seen before) or in an obvious location that is unfamiliar to you (such as behind a door, around a corner, or in a grove of trees).
> You can use the chosen sense through the sensor as if you were in its space.

- **Circle of the Moon Druid** level 10 with Elemental Wild Shape, turning into an Earth Elemental. This comes with both burrownig speed and built-in Tremorsense out to 60 feet

Obviously, when transformed into the elemental, you could not use Rocket Launchers or other equipment you have, so this may not satisfy your need (but it does answer the question, I think).

Answer (score 3):

**Option #1: 7th level Warlock**

The optional [Ghostly Gaze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/subclasses#EldritchInvocations) warlock invocation *(found in XGtE)* is available to 7th level warlocks and allows:

> As an action, you gain the ability to see through solid objects to a range of 30 feet.

The downside is that it's only usable for one minute, once per Short Rest. However, if your warlock also chooses [*Pact of the Chain*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#ClassFeatures) and the [*Voice of the Chain Master*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#ClassFeatures) invocation, you can get access to several improved familiars that can be [*Invisible*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/appendix-a-conditions#Invisible) **and** whose senses you can see and hear through. With practice, this will allow you to ballpark a travel direction, especially when coupled with a feat like [Keen Mind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/keen-mind).

---

**Option #2: Homebrew a spell**

Another option is to homebrew a *Tremorsense* spell. [Darkvision](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkvision) is a 2nd level spell, has a duration of 8 hours and a range of 60 feet. I can't imagine a DM allowing you to have the [Claws of the Umber Hulk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/claws-of-the-umber-hulk) and *not* allowing you to homebrew a simple 2nd level spell.

Comment: Hi @aaron9eee, Ghostly Gaze is from Xanathar, your link goes to the core warlock page which does not list it (not an issue as you quote the text, but confusing).

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Sry! I've got all the  DDB things, so it all shows up under the warlock class as if it were all in the PHB. I'll adjust my answer to be more specific. TX for letting me know!